# Ubuntu one, music streaming

Tags: ubuntu-one, streaming

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10, and just signed up for Ubuntu One and Ubuntu One Music. Generally file sync is working fine, but music has been a complete failure so far. Here's what I'm looking at:

After 24 hours, not a single mp3 or ogg file from my laptop has sync'd to the Cloud Music folder.

I have 4 gigs of data used, which is definitely not enough to include music files. That's about the right amount for my docs and photos. With music, it should be more like 13 gigs.

No music shows up on the Ubuntu One Music app on my phone, nor on the web view of my Ubuntu One Cloud folder I followed all the online instructions I could find. Basically, on my laptop, right click on the Music folder and select "Ubuntu One > Synchronize this folder"

The Music folder now has a green check mark on it indicating its sync'd

The Ubuntu One app on my laptop says "File Sync is up to date"

I did provide credit card information, and on the Ubuntu One website "Music Streaming" is listed as one of my services.

So what am I doing wrong?

Just read this post as I'm experiencing the same problem, the answer for this post says that due to the large number of files trying to be uploaded, that it could take up to a week. However I am, as above also being told that "File sync is up to date" Can somebody confirm that this is a bug and that I just need to wait for File sync to actually be up to date? Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu One Music - Music folder won't sync](http://askubuntu.com/questions/96402/ubuntu-one-music-music-folder-wont-sync)

Answer (score 1):

Is your music showing up at https://one.ubuntu.com/files? If so, then there appears to be a problem with scanning that music so it shows up on the mobile app or web. If the music doesn't show up there then there is a problem with the files not syncing properly. Either way, can you please contact Ubuntu One support directly at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact? You can reply to the auto-reply email and include log files that will help us troubleshoot this problem:

1. Open your home folder
2. Click the View->Show Hidden Files menu option
3. Open the .cache/ubuntuone folder
4. Right click on the log folder and select "Compress"
5. Click OK and you should have a file named "log.tar.gz" in the .cache/ubuntuone folder, move this file to your Desktop since it's in a hidden folder which can be hard to find in the next step
6. Reply to the email and attach the log.tar.gz folder